# Difference between mongoengine and django-mongo-engine and pymongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, python-3.6

Can anyone explain me the difference between mongoengine and django-mongo-engine and pymongo.

I am trying to connect to mongodb Database in Django2.0 and python3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyMongo vs MongoEngine for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712857/pymongo-vs-mongoengine-for-django)

Comment: does mongoengine work with django2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple DBs (in Mongo itself) and need to switch DB for long time, then don't go for `mongoengine`.

For simple interaction mongoengine is a nice option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [django-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) is basically a fork of [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/). However, django-mongoengine is not yet ready for production use; the README of the repo states, "*THIS IS UNSTABLE PROJECT, IF YOU WANT TO USE IT - FIX WHAT YOU NEED*."

[pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/#) is a full-featured, but low-level, MongoDB library. Unlike [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/), it does not provide ORM.

That being said, mongoengine is your best bet, since it has a clean ORM which is similar to using models in Django, it's under active development, and it's used in production.